# Solve the system of partial differential equations for 4 variable function

Tags: combinatorics, partial-differential-equations

Let $G=G(x,y,u,v)$ and let consider the following system of equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial y}=uv \,G,\\
\displaystyle x\frac{\partial G}{ \partial y}-y \frac{\partial G}{ \partial x}=v\frac{\partial G}{ \partial u}- u \frac{\partial G}{ \partial v}
\end{cases}
$$

By experiments I have found one solution $$G=e^{xu+yv}$$  but I think that must be one more solution.
Any ideas how to find all independent solutions?

PS. The first equation has solution

$$
G=C {{ e}^{{\frac {vyu+x \left( {\it f} \left( u,v \right)  \right) ^{
2}}{{\it f} \left( u,v \right) }}}}
$$
where  $f$ is arbitrary function.

Comment: OK. $\quad G=C e^{\frac {vy}{f(u,v)}+uxf(u,v)}\quad$ is solution of the first PDE. But I think it isn't a solution of the problem because it doesn't satisfy the second PDE. A solution of the problem is $\quad G=f(u^2+v^2) e^{\pm(vy+ux)}\quad$ because it satisfies both PDEs.

Comment: @JJacquelin  Is there one more solution?

Comment: $$G(x,y,u,v)=f(u^2+v^2)e^{xu+yv}+g(u^2+v^2)e^{-(xu+yv)}$$ is more general because two independant arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$ are involved. Nothing proves that it is the general solution because the method used for finding them is the method of separation of variables for the first PDE. This method doesn't give  necessarily all solutions. Giving a definitive answer to your question is something else. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One can analytically solve the second PDE :
$$x\frac{\partial G}{ \partial y}-y \frac{\partial G}{ \partial x}=v\frac{\partial G}{ \partial u}- u \frac{\partial G}{ \partial v}$$
$$xG_y-yG_x-vG_u+uG_v=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{du}{-v}=\frac{dv}{u}=\frac{dG}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dx}{-y}$
$$x^2+y^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{du}{-v}=\frac{dv}{u}$
$$u^2+v^2=c_2$$
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{du}{v}=\frac{dx}{\pm\sqrt{c_1-x^2}}=\frac{du}{\pm\sqrt{c_2-u^2}}$
$$\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u})=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE $\quad G=\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)\quad$ is :
$$\boxed{G(x,y,u,v)=\Phi\left((x^2+y^2)\:,\:(u^2+v^2)\:,\:\left(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u})\right) \right)}$$
$\Phi(X,Y,Z)$ is an arbitrary function of three variables :
$\quad\begin{cases}
X=x^2+y^2\\
Y=u^2+y^2\\
Z=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u})
\end{cases}$

Alternatively this result can be obtained in polar coordinates instead of in Cartesian.
$$\begin{cases}
x=\rho\cos{\alpha}\\
y=\rho\sin{\alpha}
\end{cases}\quad
\begin{cases}
u=\mu\cos{\beta}\\
v=\mu\sin{\beta}
\end{cases}$$
After expressing $G_x$ and $G_y$ in terms of $G_\rho$ and $G_\alpha$ as well as $G_u$ and $G_v$ in terms of $G_\mu$ and $G_\beta$ the PDE simplifies a lot and becomes very simple :
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial \beta}=0$$
which general solution is :
$$\boxed{G(\rho,\mu,\alpha,\beta)=\Psi(\rho,\mu,\alpha-\beta)}$$
$\psi$ is an arbitrary function of three variables.

Back to Cartesian :
$$G(x,y,u,v)=\Psi\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\:,\:\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\:,\:\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u}) \right)$$
This is equivalent to the above result since $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are arbitrary functions.

The above calculus leads to an infinity many solutions for the second PDE. Then one think to put the above general solution $G(x,y,u,v)$ into the first PDE
$\quad\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial y}=uv \,G\quad$ in order to determine the function $\Phi$ and find the whole set of solutions of the coupled PDEs.

That is a different kettle of fish. So the problem is far to be fully solved. Hopping that the above calculus help.

NOTE :

The solution $G=c\:e^{xu+yv}$ corresponds to the particular case of
$$\Psi(\rho,\mu,\alpha-\beta)=c\:e^{\,\rho\,\mu\,\cos(\alpha-\beta)}.$$

$$G=c\:e^{-(xu+yv)}\quad\text{is another solution.}$$
As well as linear combinations :
$$G=c\:\cosh(xu+yv)$$
$$G=c\:\sinh(xu+yv)$$
$c$ : arbitrary constants.

More solutions can be found on the form :
$$G(x,y,u,v)=f(u^2+v^2)e^{xu+yv}+g(u^2+v^2)e^{-(xu+yv)}$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thank you. We may some simplify it. Since 
$$
\cos \left( \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u}) \right)=\frac{xu+yv}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}  \sqrt{u^2+v^2}}
$$  thus $Z$ can be $xu+yv.$  Also I solve the second equation ( See changes in my question), but how to solve the  whole  system?

Comment: *second=first...